# java - original message headers from undelivered mails

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have to get the message headers of original message sent from the **undelivered mails**.

Purpose : To check for which mail the reply is,for the other mails I am using **In-Reply-To** and **Message-ID** to relate them but in case of undelivered mails the header changes there in no such **In-Reply-To** field in header.
If i could be able to get original message headers i think this cloud be solved.

Sample code for what i have done till now

```
  Properties props = System.getProperties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailHostName());
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailSmtpSocketFactoryPort());
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailSMTPSocketFactoryClass());
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailSmtpAuth());
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailSmtpSocketFactoryPort());
                String userid = AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailId();
                String password = AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailPassword();

                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
                Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

                store.connect(props.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"), userid, password);

                Folder inbox = (Folder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
                inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();
                profile.add(FetchProfileItem.CONTENT_INFO);
                profile.add("X-mailer");
                Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(inbox.getMessageCount() - 10, inbox.getMessageCount());
                inbox.fetch(messages, profile);


                for (Message message : messages) {

    System.out.println(message.getHeader("Message-ID")[0]);
    System.out.println(message.getHeader("In-Reply-To")[0]);

                }

                inbox.close(true);

                store.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're lucky, the 'other' smtp has returned them. In that case you can access them through [MultipartReport](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/dsn/MultipartReport.html):

```
for (Message message : messages) {
 if(message instanceof MimeMessage) {
    MimeMessage mime = (MimeMessage)message;
    Object content = mime.getContent();
    if(content instanceof MultipartReport) {
       MultipartReport dsn = (MultipartReport)content;
       MimeMessage m = dsn.getReturnedMessage();
       if(m != null) {
          // Tadaa - headers are here:
          String originalMessageId = m.getMessageID();
       }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: IMAPMessage extends MimeMessage. They are.

Comment: Actually i was asking if(content instanceof MultipartReport) return false

Comment: actually mail content coming inline in message

Comment: Might depend on your mail server /mail client and other stuff. You could try a message.writeTo(System.out); and have a look at the structure.

Comment: yup like this Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     xyz@abc.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
DNS Error: Address resolution of abc.com. failed: Domain name not found

----- Original message -----

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X-Received: by 10.66.216.200 with SMTP id os8mr79503986pac.143.1451313118192;
        Mon, 28 Dec 2015 06:31:58 -0800 (PST)

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: so in this case i would have to parse the content using regular expression or so...

Comment: in that case your imap server did conversion already - bad for you. I guess regex would be good then.

Comment: there is no content to parse or no in-reply-to field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99183/discussion-between-pawan-pandey-and-jan).